# What is the difference between "Come on home" and "Come home"?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

What is the difference between "Come on home" and "Come home"? In this case "Come on" is a phrasal verb?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question.

Yes, I think *come on* is a phrasal verb, and a rather colloquial one. I'm finding it hard to define its meaning though. Sometimes it does mean the same as *come*, with a connotation of either annoyance or invitation (depending on the tone of voice). It can also have a much more abstract meaning, something like "I want you to do something, or finish something".

In this case, your two sentences do have the same meaning, but *come on home* is more friendly, either coaxing or inviting.

Comment: The same "superficially superfluous" preposition usage occurs in [*go on over*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22go+on+over+to%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), where I think the [optional] ***over*** imparts a sense of "continuity" or "immediacy". That's to say you if you *go on over to [your friend's house, say]*, this is often in contexts where the visit is *the next activity* within a series of reported or planned activities. It may also imply addition to or diversion from a simpler series of activities.

Comment: What a lot of things we use _on_ to mean. I agree, the pragmatic usages ('oiling' the discourse: friendly, encouraging // hectoring, threatening ) are important. 'Come' on its own sounds faintly ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

`Come on home` could be taken to imply that the person you're talking to is already on their way home, and you're welcoming them in advance.

`Come home` might be more of a request - this person isn't necessarily thinking about coming home and you're suggesting it in the hope they will.

These are the two meanings I would first assume if, for example, I overheard them on one end of a phone-call.